# Mclust Output Interpretation

Tags: r, output, cluster-analysis

When I performed the *mclustModel* the output that was give to me was different from usual output.

Usually the output is like this:

```
$z[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]


1  1  0   0  0  0

2  0  1   0  0  0

3  0  0   1  0  0

4  1  0   0  0  0

5  0  0   1  0  0
```

and so on.

However, this time the out put was like this:

```
$z    [,1]       [,2]      [,3]

1  1.000000e+00 0.0000000    0

2  1.000000e+00 0.0000000    0
3  1.000000e+00 0.0000000    0
4  1.000000e+00 0.0000000    0
5  1.000000e+00 0.0000000    0
6  5.058816e-65 1.0000000    0
7 2.042567e-72 0.0000000    1
```

each number bellow the %z represent one individual, and the other columns the clusters, in the second output looks like the same individual could be in two different clusters. Is that right or is it some error?

I used the following code:

```
library(foreign)

library(mclust)

idd<- read.dta(data)

idd_ss <-subset(idd,select=c(variable1, variable2, variabel3, variable4, variable5))

iddBIC<- mclustBIC(idd_ss)

cl <- mclustModel(idd_ss,iddBIC)

cl
```

￼￼

Comment: Which line do you see as being an entry in two different clusters? From the help doc, z is "A matrix whose [i,k]th entry is the probability that observation i in the test data belongs to the kth class." So as long as the rowSums(z) are all equal to 1, it's functioning correctly, and all the lines you have posted seem to sum to ~1.

Comment: However there are lines with values in two columns, such as column 7: value 2.0... in the column 1 and value 1 in the column 3.

It doesn't seen that the probability is 2.04... for column 1 and probability of 1 to column 3?

Comment: You're missing the exponent -  that's 2.04e-72 = 2.04 x 10^-72 ~ 0

Comment: Do you have any idea why it happens? 

Does it means there are possibilities, or probabilities, it belongs to two clusters? or are there change it is a error?

Comment: It is not an error. Each column in the output represents a cluster. The numbers in the table are the probability that the entry/person is in the cluster represented by each column. So, yes, each entry has a probability of belonging to multiple clusters.